# [UPDATED]Can's seed data in a table with FK

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

There two tables

User and Preference. User has FK Preference.
Trying to add data to both tables using migration.

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().OwnsOne(p => p.Preference).HasData(
            new Preference
            {
                Id = Guid.Parse("A6293AB4-3A1B-4780-F207-0BC92650778B"),
                //other properties
            }
        );

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasData(new User
        {
            Id = Guid.Parse("f90gh1b1-c121-4962-sa96-5c6fdb2af1ab"),
            //some other properties...
            
        });
```

Error I am getting when running add migration command.

```
The seed entity for entity type 'Preference' cannot be added because no value was provided for the required property 'UserId'.
```

There is no PreferenceId in User. Only Preference object.
In cs files, User.cs has

```
    public virtual Preference Preference { get; set; } = null!;
```

UPDATE
I added `public Guid PreferenceId{get;set;}` to User.cs, changed the code like this :

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasData(new User
        {
            Id = Guid.Parse("f90gh1b1-c121-4962-sa96-5c6fdb2af1ab"),
            //some other properties...
            PreferenceId = Guid.Parse(someGuid)
        });
```

REMOVED OwnsOne part.
Updated DB and the record was added. How do I know if this was added as FK or not?

Answer (score 0):

By adding the `public virtual Preference Preference { get; set; } = null!;` into your user class it creates the FK to preferences.

One way to do it would be to create a new user object and set the preferences variable to an object. e.g.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasData(new User
    {
        Id = Guid.Parse("f90gh1b1-c121-4962-sa96-5c6fdb2af1ab"),
        Preference = new Preference
        {
            Id = Guid.Parse("A6293AB4-3A1B-4780-F207-0BC92650778B"),
            //other properties
        }

        //some other properties...
        
    });
```

Hope I am understanding the question correctly

Comment: In that case I would get "The seed entity for entity type 'User' cannot be added because no value was provided for the required property 'PreferenceId'."

Comment: If that is being migrated to a SQL database you will find that a preferenceId column would be added to the User table. is there a reference to the user class in the preference class?

Comment: No. There is no reference to User table in Preference table

Comment: When you use model seed data, even if your primary key is set to be generated by the database, you need to specify the primary key value.
For more explanation, please check this link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding#limitations-of-model-seed-data

Comment: I did put primary keys manually

Comment: https://itecnote.com/tecnote/c-the-seed-entity-for-entity-type-x-cannot-be-added-because-the-was-no-value-provided-for-the-required-property-id/ <-- more information here

Comment: Or create a preference object then when creating the user object specify the Preference ID using the ID you created. you might need to add a preferenceID variable to the User class with the foreign key attribute.

Comment: Please avoid extended discussion here - that's not what comments are for.